# Saving CPU/memory trend in file

Tags: bash, process, pipe, io-redirection

A command like `top | grep chromium` is giving me a time trend over CPU and memory load to **STDOUT**. I am trying to pipe this output to a file with `top | grep chromium >> load.log` which fails (no error but **load.log** stays empty).

- Is the problem the time varying output of `top`?
- How can I solve this issue without using external tools solely using Bash?
- How can I adjust the update time?

Comment: are you sure it is empty? Try `watch -n1 ls -l load.log` to see whether its size grows. `top` generates tones of output, buffering shouldn't be an issue. To remove ANSI code (colors, cursor movements) you could pass `-b` flag to `top`.

Comment: Now I feel really stupid. I don't know why but now its growing even withput the line-buffering...

Comment: Well OK it just starts to write after approx. 30 seconds. That's exactly the point @John Kugelman was speaking about. It takes so long until 4096 bytes are in the memory. Afterwards the writing to the file starts.

Comment: yes. It uses 4KB buffer on my machine too. But it is full in *3* seconds for `top | grep chrom >>load.log` command and the file starts grow almost immediately for `top | grep --libe-buffered chrom >>load.log` command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
top | grep --line-buffered chromium >> load.log
```

When grep writes to a tty its output is line buffered. When it's redirected to a file its output is fully buffered, meaning it only flushes every 4096 bytes. The `--line-buffered` option overrides this behavior, forcing it to flush stdout after every line.

This behavior isn't unique to grep; it can happen with any standard C program that uses libc. You can use [`stdbuf`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) to force an arbitrary program to be line-buffered.

```
top | stdbuf -oL grep chromium >> load.log
```

Comment: I also figured how to change the refreshing time: E.g. `top -d 10` will output the load after 10 seconds. Now I only have to filter the data with `awk`, mark via time stamp using `date` and I'm fine. Thx a lot John!